# Mixed solar and wind farm

Tags: solar-energy, power-generation

Is there any reason why solar and wind farms cannot share the same piece of land?
The number of solar arrays that would have to be omitted to make way for the turbines should be relatively few. The advantages are:

1. Dual use of the land, (more power per square metre) and you could still graze animals.
2. Shared use of much of the infrastructure such as transformers, switchgear and cables.
3. Somewhat more even supply, more chance that the site would be producing something 24/7.
4. Possibly output would be less weather dependent. I can't say for sure, but sunny days tend to be calm (Summer high pressure weather systems) and cloudy days are windy (Winter weather). This is a generalisation with exceptions and caveats.

There would be downsides, higher capital investment and sunny sites are not necessarily windy and vice versa. However they both are often found on less productive agricultural land, so in that respect vie for similar sites. But on the whole are there any technical disadvantages?

Comment: The wind turbines cast large shadows across the solar panels rendering them less effective.

Comment: How do you graze animals on land that is mostly shaded by solar panels?

Comment: @Andyaka Somewhat, but that depends on the wind direction and the orientation and layout of the arrays. In the northern hemisphere arrays face South. The predominant wind direction in the UK is from the West. Therefore the shadow of the turbines would be North-South and narrow. Again a sweeping generalisation.

Comment: @DaveTweed Apparently it's fairly common practice. There is still enough light reaching the ground for grass to grow suitable for sheep. The panels are mounted high enough that the sheep can walk underneath them. Google "grazing sheep on solar farm" for more information and several images of it happening.

Comment: "*...  but that depends on the wind direction and the orientation and layout of the arrays.*" The shadows are cast by the sun, not the wind. The problem is that blocking one panel in an array of series panels may cause problems.

Comment: @Transistor: That's a minor technical detail that is already solved in most solar arrays. It's easy to bypass a shaded panel.

Comment: @Transistor The solar shadow of the turbines will be mostly oriented N-S (Westerly winds). The wind shadow of the solar arrays will be negligible as they are essentially at ground level and the bottom of the sweep of the turbine blades will be several metres above this. Again it's all a matter of design.

Comment: @DaveTweed From the Google answers,you can also run chickens and geese under solar arrays. Presumably other small farm livestock are possible.

Comment: Then you start to get secondary issues, such as the animals creating extra dust and dirt that needs to be cleaned off the panels more frequently.

Comment: The panels get in the way of machinery used for turbine maintenance.

Answer (score 0):

There is no reason you cannot consider this if you are aware of all requirements.

I remember seeing a website to compute utilization and compute GTI supply availability and need for storage capacity for shared wind and solar farms just the other day on a US govt energy site, where depending on your design you can enter all the variables.

However Logistics , clearances , safety factors and local constraints or regulations were not discussed.

https://canwea.ca/blog/2018/02/21/wind-farms-land-use/
￼
￼

Panels and rotor turbulence needs to be well above the weed and grazing clearances.

https://www.cbc.ca/news/canada/ottawa/solar-energy-panels-weeds-sheep-lambs-farming-grazing-1.5190376

￼
￼